# How to remove Extra space below the footer?

Tags: footer

i have problem with my page, when it reaches to 768X1024 a big space below my footer exist, i looked some answers here at stackoverflow but i can't find one. can you help to fix it?

```
here's my http://jsfiddle.net/craybac/pb0d6zda/5/
```

and here's the image problem:

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: There's no js fiddle link

Comment: use position:absolute; instead of relative

Answer (score 0):

Use `postion:absolute`,solve your problem.

here is

[fiddle link:](http://jsfiddle.net/znc4k0z7/)

Still your problem is not solved.use the below css

```
html,
body{
height:100%;
}
```

use some id wrapper after body and close that tag in before closing body tag.
and add the below css.

```
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative
}
```

Comment: it didn't solve. the footer went in the middle of the page by adding position:absolute;

Comment: did you check the fiddle link i posted in my answer?

Comment: yes, i saw the fiddle that's why i tried the position:absolute;

Comment: @edtdesign,try my new answer

Comment: @edtdesign,use % instead of px and use wrapper.

Comment: there is a big space when it reaches to 768x1024 but in other sizes it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute instead of position relative

```
.footer {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: there's still a big white space even i changed to position:absolute;

Comment: @egtdesign Actually in your fiddle I have just changed the position:relative to position:absolute. Then It worked. Just try it in your fiddle

Comment: yes it changed in the fiddle but in the actual the big white space is still there.

Comment: i noticed that having less content in the body will result a big white space, is there any solution for this?